# pm clear not logout apps like twitter

Tags: adb, shell

I'm doing:

```
pm clear com.twitter.android
```

And expecting to be log out from twitter app. But it is not working. I also tried to clear every app package with `pm list packages -f`, in case twitter store login key in some other system app.

But this didn't work too.

I tried also to remove all folders from `/data/data/com.twitter.android`

And I still logged in

Comment: So if you open the Twitter app after clearing it's data you are still logged on? Have you tried to delete the account in the account list?

Comment: @Robert yes, I still logged in. I tried also to remove all folders from /data/data/com.twitter.android

Comment: @Robert what is account list ?

Comment: Android settings -> Accounts -> Twitter account

Comment: @Robert oh, yes... Is this possible to remove it through the adb shell ? I tried this:
https://blog.shadura.me/2012/05/07/removing-accounts-from-android-devices/

but I don't have .db file in /data/system/

Comment: The post is from 2012 - Google changes Android way too often. Therefore I would recommend not to directly alter the database. This approach seems to be better and works even without root: https://github.com/KazuCocoa/DroidTestHelper

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92428/discussion-between-robert-and-arti).